# TypeError: Cannot read property '_applyBodyHighContrastModeCssClasses' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am encountering this error when starting up angular. The app builds fine until the web pages loads, and this error is shown when inspecting the web browser and nothing is rendered in the web page.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_applyBodyHighContrastModeCssClasses' of undefined

at new MatCommonModule (core.js:101)
at Object.factory (core.js:11310)
at R3Injector.hydrate (core.js:11363)
at R3Injector.get (core.js:11183)
at core.js:11220
at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
at R3Injector._resolveInjectorDefTypes (core.js:11220)
at new NgModuleRef$1 (core.js:25231)
at NgModuleFactory$1.create (core.js:25285)
at core.js:29112
```

I tried to update individual packages for angular material and cdk package.
This is my package.json to  try and reproduce the error. Does it have something to do with certain dependency injection error in angular.

```
{
  "name": "sgmreporting-front-end",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/localize": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/material": "^11.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.4",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^9.0.2",
    "@types/highcharts": "^7.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "flexmonster": "^2.8.28",
    "highcharts": "^9.0.1",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "ng-flexmonster": "^2.8.28",
    "ngx-toastr": "^13.2.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.6",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1102.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: could you please add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). you could use [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)

Comment: @IsmailDinar I have no way of replicating the error as this is something to do with package installations

Comment: I have same error here, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I too have just experienced the same problem, I have downgraded the dependences @angular /...@11.1.0 and typescript a 4.0.6 everything is back to normal

you do an npm install --force @angular /....@ 11.1.0 of all dependences and also downgrade typscript to version 4.0.6

Comment: Firstly, thank you. This sorted my problem too.

Secondly, Do you have a reason for this?
Does this mean that we will be stock at this version forever?

Comment: no, I think the new version will fix this, there are a lot of people encountered the same problem and they had to report it on the github tab from angular

Comment: Many thanks for the reply @ebed meleck.  Do you have a link to where people were reporting it?  
Also can I ask what "new version" are you referring to

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by upgrading to version @angular/...@11.2.9 and @angular/cli to version 11.2.8, then upgraded typescript to version 4.1.5